# Check checkBox when data is entered in textbox inside a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if it is possible to `'Checked=true'` the checkBox of the ROW when data is entered in textbox inside a table.

here is the code jquery code to do this, but is checking all the checkboxes. I will appreciate any help.

jquery code:

```
<script>
    jQuery('[id$="enteredValue"]').change(function() {
        jQuery('[id$="check"]').attr('checked', true);
    });
</script>
```

html code

```
<table id="table-2">
    <thead>             
        <tr>
            <th>Select</th>                                
            <th>Enter Qty</th>
            <th> Suggested Units</th>
            <th> Cost</th>
            <th>Brand</th>
        </tr>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><apex:inputCheckbox id="check" value="{!objectRow.selected}"/>  </td>
            <td><apex:inputText id="enteredValue" value=" {!objectRow.EnteredValue}"  /></td>
            <td><apex:outputText value="{!objectRow.Reorder_Amount}"/></td>
            <td><apex:outputText value="{!objectRow.Reorder_Cost}" /></td>
            <td><apex:outputText value="{!objectRow.Brand}"  /></td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
<script>
    jQuery('[id$="enteredValue"]').change(function() {
         $(this).closest('tr').find('[id$="check"]').prop('checked', true);
         if(this.val()=="")
         {
             $(this).closest('tr').find('[id$="check"]').prop('checked', false);
         }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Jameen, thank you for your help, but i used 'tr' instead of 'td' and it worked

Comment: how about if the user delete whatever is inside the texfield, how can I create a function that unchecked the checkbox. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you *are* selecting *all* checkboxes. Only select the one that is in the row of the text input:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('[id$="check"]').prop('checked', true);
```

If you pass a boolean as value, use `prop` instead. See https://api.jquery.com/attr/ for more info.